# Append an element to a double embedded dictionary adds to all parent elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a little bit stumped by a problem which I can't figure out and I feel it should be a trivial problem to solve.

I have an element *budget* of class Budget. In this class, it has a dictionary *sections* which contains *Section* class objects. In *Section* class, I have another dictionary which is called *allowances* of *Allowance* class objects. In the *Allowance* class, I have a list called *operations* to which I want to add *Operation* class objects. The hierarchy is as follows, for those a bit more visual :

*budget* -> *sections* -> *allowances* -> *operations*

I want to append an Operation class object to a specific combination of section and allowance (variables used are *name_of_section* and *name_of_operation*. My first try was

```
budget.sections[name_of_section].allowances[name_of_allowance].operations.append(Operation(name=name,
                                                                                           cost=cost, date=date)
```

For some unknown reason, it adds the Operation object to all my *sections* and *allowances* elements and I can't figure out why. I tried adding a method *add_operation()* to *Section*, which uses a method *add_operation()* to *Allowance*, but it just keeps adding every operation to all my *Section* and *Allowance* elements.

The weirdest thing is that I also have a list *keywords* in *Allowance* which is meant to be a list of strings. I append a string just a few lines later in exactly the same fashion:

```
budget.sections[name_of_section].allowances[name_of_allowance].keywords.append(keyword_str)
```

And it only adds to the appropriate section and allowance. Does anyone have an idea why when I'm trying to append my Operation object to a list, it adds to all the lists, although when I append to a list of str, it only adds to a single and the appropriate list?

Here's my *Budget* initialization and method to add an allowance which adds a section as needed.

```py
def __init__(self):
    self.sections = {"Income": Section(name = "Income")}
    self.total_balance = 0.0
    self.unsorted_operations = []

def add_allowance(self, name, section, projected_cost = 0.0, frequency = "monthly"):
    if section in self.sections:
        self.sections[section].new_allowance(name=name, section=section, projected_cost = projected_cost,
                                             frequency = frequency)
    else:
        self.add_section(name = section)
        self.sections[section].new_allowance(name=name, section=section, projected_cost=projected_cost,
                                             frequency=frequency)
```

My *Section* class is initialized in this fashion and the _new_allowance()_ method is:

```py
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.allowances = dict()
    self.calculate_projected_cost()

def new_allowance(self, name, section, projected_cost, frequency = 'monthly'):
    self.allowances[name] = Allowance(name = name, section = section, projected_cost = projected_cost,
                                      frequency = frequency)
    self.calculate_projected_cost()
```

My *Allowance* class is initialized this way:

```py
def __init__(self, name, section, projected_cost = 0.0, frequency = "monthly"):
    self.name = name
    self.section = section
    self.operations = []
    self.cost = 0.0
    self.frequency = frequency
    self.calculate_projected_cost(projected_cost, frequency)
    self.keywords = []
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `budget`? How are creating `sections` and `allowances`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it might had been a problem with my saved JSON file which I loaded my `budget` object from. As J_H suggested to use `id(x)`, the elements were one and the same. This tip was quite useful in debugging my problem.

Without any change to the code and by starting from scratch instead of loading my JSON file, I did not see that kind of behavior again. I saved it, stopped the program, ran it again and loaded my new saved file, and now, it is running as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you created your data structure,
as you didn't post that code.

But your symptom makes it clear that you did something like this:

```
>>> a = ['apple']
>>> fruit = [a, a, a]
>>> a.append('banana')
>>> fruit
[['apple', 'banana'], ['apple', 'banana'], ['apple', 'banana']]
```

That is, you have an inner mutable container (or similar object),
and your outer container has multiple references to that single inner container.
Suppose you display the outer container.
Now you change the inner container (`a`, above) --
that will affect the displayed output in multiple places,
since you have multiple references to what changed.

If you're curious about details you can use e.g.
`print(list(map(id, fruit)))` to see whether elements
are the same or different.
The python `id(x)` function is roughly equivalent
to a C program asking at which address was
storage for `x` allocated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input J_H. I'll add my code for each initialization a bit later, I was just trying your tip quickly. Using your tip about printing the "address", it showed that each address was the same indeed. I was loading a JSON file to pick up my work without having to do all the user inputs every time I ran my script. I started from scratch, and it didn't reproduce the same behaviour and it behaves as intended. It seems like part of the problem might come from there. More to come a bit later.